# Features of PostGIS layer are only selectable in attribute table but non on map canvas

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql

My features of a PostGIS layer are displayed in the map canvas in QGIS and projected properly at the right place.

They **are not** selectable in graphically in the map. But they **are** selectable in attribute table.

So it does not seem to be a problem of granting rights to select/edit the data.

My PostgreSQL 12 server contains 2 databases. All tables of all schemas of just one from the databases show these behaviour. In the other database every geodata-behavoiur is as expected in QGIS.

Inserting test data/tables in the PostgreSQL scheme via QGIS-database-export throws following exception:
Function addgeometrycolumn(unknown, unknown, unknown, integer, unknown, integer) is not unique.

*(It's no problem to create (new) views within the misbehaving scheme)*

Any idea what went wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: Do you have geometries with different SRIDs in your table? Is the SRID clearly defined in your PostGIS table?

Comment: I think so. Every geometrycolumn is created in a view like           CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW myscheme.myview
 AS
 SELECT 
   …mycontent
    st_geometryfromtext(((('POINT ('::text || table.x_coord) || ' '::text) || table.y_coord) || ')'::text, 25832) AS the_geom
   FROM myscheme.mytable table;

Comment: QGIS project is in 25832 too. Have got just one table (i.e. the view above) in a sample project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We solved the problem: During a database-upgrade from pg 9.1 to pg 12 some of the "old" postgis functions were restored to the new database. After creating the new postgis-extension we had some functions twice or more times, which led to the problems.

To solve the issue we created a new database with a fresh postgis-extension and transferred just the data without any functions.

Comment: You can accept your answer with the checkbox